# REST API POST - Check if each nested object exists. If no, create new. If yes, return existing object

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, api-design

I'm somewhat new to  `RESTful API` design practice and looking for help. The data model I'm working with details a top-level object (e.g. Book) containing a list of a nested objects (e.g. Chapters).
Each Chapter is persisted in its own right and has a `simple_name` field that is set to `unique=True` (ie. only **one** Chapter with *Chapter.simple_name* = "ch_01" may exist).

> **Scenario**: A user POSTs a Book ("myBook_v1") containing Chapters, "ch_01", "ch_02", and "ch_03". The user then edits their book and the
>   next day POSTs "myBook_v2" containing Chapters, "ch_01", "ch_02",
>   "ch_03", **and "ch_04"**. Suppose that Chapters "ch_01", "ch_02",
>   "ch_03" are unchanged from the original POST.

Currently, since *simple_name* is required to be unique, the second `POST` does not pass uniqueness validation and an error response is returned to the user.

**Question**: Would the following implementation fit `REST` design principles? And, most importantly, is this a good (safe) design choice?

**Implementation**: Upon Book POST, check each *Chapter.simple_name* for uniqueness. If *Chapter.simple_name* already exists in database, skip creation. If it does not exist, create new Chapter. Return complete persisted Book with a mix of newly created Chapters and already existing Chapters. The only criteria for deciding to create new or use existing is whether or not the user-specified *simple_name* already exists for a Chapter in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to remove the uniqueness constraint by dropping the associated validator and deal with adding / updating / removing by yourself after (see [Unique validation on nested serializer on Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438167/unique-validation-on-nested-serializer-on-django-rest-framework))