# Modify read only nested fields in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I realize the title sounds silly but I want to be able to change the references to the `Group` objects for my `User` instances. But I do not want them to be able to create new groups or edit existing groups. I think what I want is a read only nested field. However, if I set it to `read_only=True` I do not get the data in my serializers validated data. If I set it to `read_only=False` then it tries to create a new `Group` instead of just changing the references.

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'name',
            'permissions',
        )

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    ....

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = (
            ....
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        return instance

    def validate_groups(self, value):
        print("validating groups")
        ....
        return value
```

With `read_only=True` nothing happens at all. I get the user back on my `PATCH` request but the user is exactly the same. With `read_only=False` I get a validation error returned to me `{'groups': [{'name': ['group with this name already exists.']}]}`

I have also tried overriding the `create` and `update` method on the `GroupSerializer` but with no change.

At most, I want the `GroupSerializer` just to validate that the group from the data exists.

Comment: This is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438167/unique-validation-on-nested-serializer-on-django-rest-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found was to use the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and that provides a read only interface where I can select items that already exists and associate them to the object.

Sadly, there is one downside which is that now when viewing those objects in a `GET` type view the details of the related object are not shown but rather just the `PK`. I will figure out a way around this soon, maybe multi-serializer viewsets will do the trick.

[Here are the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Answer (score 1):

Really late answer, but I stumbled upon this in another thread here on StackOverflow (unfortunately I can't find it now), and they referred to the following [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/django-rest-framework/XBJztipJsYE/5_JFFzrHcJQJ).

The solution I used was to create two serializers - one for reading and another one for writing - and two respective ViewSets including the correct Mixins. So I could list the nested Foreign Keys when using a GET method and only POST using the identifier for the existing Model of the FK relation. I used the `depth` attribute. I hope that relates to this problem.