# In the Django Rest Framework, how do you add ManyToMany related objects?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Here's my code:

**Models**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

**View**

```
class RecipeDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
  serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
  queryset = Recipe.objects.all()

  def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

  def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(updated_by_user=self.request.user)
```

**Serializers**

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = [
      'id',
            'name',
        ]

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  ingredient = IngredientSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

  class Meta:
    model = Recipe
    fields = [
      'id',
      'name',
      'ingredient',
    ]
```

I'm starting with the following Recipe object:

```
{
    "id": 91
    "name": "Potato Salad"
    "ingredient": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Potato"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I am attempting to update that object by **put**ting the following JSON object to the IngredientSerializer:

```
{
    "id": 91
    "name": "Potato Salad"
    "ingredient": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Potato"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Mayo"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is it to recognize that the relationship to Potato already exists and skip over that, but add a relationship to the Mayo object. Note that the Mayo object already exists in Ingredients, but is not yet tied to the Potato Salad object.

What actually happens is the Serializer tries to create a new Ingredient object and fails because "ingredient with this name already exists."

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DRF does not have any automatic "write" behavior for nested serializers, precisely because it does not know things like how to go about updates in the scenario you mentioned. Therefore, you need to write your own `update` method in your `RecipeSerializer`.

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  def validate_name(self, value):
    # manually validate
    pass

  class Meta:
    model = Ingredient
    fields = ['id', 'name']
    extra_kwargs = {
        'name': {'validators': []}, # remove uniqueness validation
    }


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  ingredient = IngredientSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredient')
    # ... logic to save ingredients for this recipe instance
    return instance

  class Meta:
    model = Recipe
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'ingredient']
```

Relevant DRF documentation:

[Saving Instances](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)

[Writable Nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

[Updating nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#updating-nested-serializers)

**Update:**

If DRF validation fails for the uniqueness constraint in the name field, you should try removing validators for that field.

**Alternative solution: Only use full serializer as read only field**

You can change you RecipeSerializer to the following:

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  ingredient_details = IngredientSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='ingredient')

  class Meta:
    model = Recipe
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'ingredient', 'ingredient_details']
```

And that's it. No need to override `update` or anything. You'll get the detailed representation when you get a recipe, and you can just PUT with the ingredient ids when updating. So your json when updating will look something like this:

```
{
    "id": 91
    "name": "Potato Salad"
    "ingredient": [5, 6]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, slider; however, this doesn't work because the data doesn't validate. The Ingredient model wants unique names, so I get a validation error before update() is called. I tried setting ReadOnly to True in the RecipeSerializer (ingredient = IngredientSerializer(many=True, read_only=True). That fixes the validation issue, but then the meal data isn't available in validated_data in update().

Comment: Ah, yes. There's a solution for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438167/unique-validation-on-nested-serializer-on-django-rest-framework Basically, you want to remove validation for the `name` field. I'll update the answer with this information.

Comment: Your alternative solution works with one change. I needed to create an ingredient_details property on the Recipe model in order to include that field in the serializer. Thanks!

Comment: @Webucator you don't need to do that. You'll have duplicate fields for the same thing. I forgot to add the `source` attribute for `ingredient_details` in the serializer (it's there now). You can have 2 serializer fields for the same model field.